# how to use onActivityResult in android more than one

Tags: android, social-networking

```
enter code here public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //If signin
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        //Calling a new function to handle signin
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
```

// this is for facebook
callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Comment: I mean more than once in your activity I need it for both facebook sign in  and Google +  sign in

Comment: You use different request codes for each, and write an if statement for each

Answer (score 0):

See developers guide http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

It depends upon your request code you give when assigning startActivity(intent,request_Code),you can have multiple actions performed.